# Incorrect filling tables by foreach

Tags: java, arrays, list, foreach

I have to fill many tables so I made arraylist of tables. Unfortunately, foreach loop doesn't add value properly.

```
private List<int[][]> orgnisms; //field in class
public Organisms(int n_tmp,int m_tmp,int mi_tmp) //constructor
{
 orgnisms= new ArrayList<>();
 newEmptyArrays(); // creates tables 5x5 filled by 0 - works
 randomValues();
}
private void randomValues(){   
    for(int[][] table : orgnisms)               // 10 tables        
    {            

            table[0][0]=1;   // ERROR - should add ONLY to [0][0], but fill other
        }
        for (int[] ii : table) {
            for (int i : ii)
                System.out.print(ii[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

For point[0][0] (like above) - three values?:

> 0**1111** 00000 00000 00000 00000

For point [1][1], method adds correctly:

> 00000 01000 00000 00000 00000

Comment: Can you show us `newEmptyArrays`?

Comment: can you show us the whole output

Comment: I didn't understand from the last lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int[] ii : table) {
    for (int i : ii)
        System.out.print(ii[i]); // <--
    System.out.println();
}
```

This is wrong. `i`, in the second loop, is **not** the index of `ii`, but the value.

Use:

```
for (int[] ii : table) {
    for (int i : ii)
        System.out.print(i); // <--
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
10000
00000
00000
00000
00000
```

Comment: An excellent example of why meaningful variable names are important.

Comment: @bradimus Yep! Also an excellent example of how important debugging is :)